# ログインとデータベース生成

Tags: mysql

SNS等でサインアップをして

次回からログインすると自分のページに入れますが

それはデータベースを生成しているのですか？

また テーブルの生成とのメリットのちがいは何ですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

回答としては
「サービスによります」
が第一になります。がそれだと面白くないと思いますので一般的な話をしておきます。

アカウントを作るたびにデータベースやテーブルを生成することはあまりなく、
アカウントテーブルにデータをINSERTして、投稿テーブルに対してはアカウントのキーを割り当てることでテーブルにINSERTします。

例えば以下のアカウントテーブルがあったとします。

| customerId | customerName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Taro |
| 2 | Hanako |

新しくアカウントを増やす場合はINSERTでIDが3のレコードが増えます。

さらに投稿テーブルがあったとします。
投稿テーブルには投稿したアカウントのIDを入れておくことで誰の投稿かわかるようにします。

| postId | postCustomerId | postText |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | はじめまして太郎といいます |
| 2 | 1 | SNSを始めてみました |
| 3 | 2 | 私が来た！ |

アカウントの数に限らず投稿の数は複数持てるので、一対多であるといえます。
こういったデータ間の関係性を表すのを「関係モデル」といいその関係モデルと実現したデータ構造がMySQLをはじめとするリレーショナルテータベースです。

SQLで取得するさいはきちんと自分のIDのデータだけ取ってくるようにすることで
それ以外のデータが混じらないようにアプリで制御しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます 

idとpostidを紐付けるには

joinすればいいんですか？

Comment: JOINを使うのはデータ参照時にアカウントテーブルの情報を一度に取得したい場合に利用します。単純に制約したいならば[外部キー制約](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/create-table-foreign-keys.html)を利用します。

Comment: ありがとうございます またデータベース毎ではなくテーブル毎にカギをかけることはできますか？

Comment: 完全な新しい質問は新たに投稿をお願いします

Comment: わかりました ただデータベースとphpファイル等をあずける場所がひつようとおもうのですが なにが一般的ですか？

Comment: その質問もこの回答には関係のない事柄のように思います。新たに質問をお願いします

Comment: また 追記なのですがテーブルにinsertした場合 ユーザーはログイン時どうするのでしょうか？ じぶんのテーブルも作成されないとのことなので

Comment: ログイン時に自分のテーブルが必要な理由がわかりませんでした。回答にある通りアプリのアカウントごとに専用のテーブルを作ることはしないです。

Comment: テーブルのカラムにログインするという方法がわからないので

Comment: 「テーブルのカラムにログインする」という仕様は私もよくわからないです。それを考えた人に聞いてみたほうが早いかと。「PHP ログイン機能」で調べればいくつも記事が出てくるのでまずはそれを参考にしてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

あなたが言う「データベース」が、何を指しているかで、回答が変わってきます。
[データベース - ウィクショナリー](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9)

広義的な意味で、「様々な情報を、電子計算機（コンピューター）を用いて検索することができるように体系的に構成したもの」という意味でしたら、答えは「Yes」です。
少なくとも、ログインに使う認証情報などが、ログインしたサービスを動かしているコンピューターのどこかに記録されます。

「[データベース管理システム (DBMS)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0)」を指しているのでしたら、ログインするサービスによるでしょう。
一般的に、ログインを必要とする大半のサービスは、 MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Microsoft SQL Server, MongoDB, Redis 等々... と言った、 DBMS に情報を記録しているでしょう。
しかし、理論上はどこかに情報が記録さえされていれば良いので、極端な話 DBMS を使わずに XML のテキストファイルに記録してもサービスは作れます。
このため、世の中には DBMS を使っていないサービスも、探せばあると思われます。

ちなみに、一般的に DBMS が利用されるのは、 記録や検索を高速に効率よく行えたり、 複数のユーザーが同時にサービスにアクセスするような対応を、サポートしやすいからですね。

Comment: mysql です